# Replace in Ruby commas by different strings

Tags: ruby, string, replace

I have a string called "example", like this:

192.168.1.40,8.8.8.8,12.34.45.56,408,-,1812
192.168.1.128,192.168.101.222,12.34.45.56,384,-,1807

and I would like to obtain this output:

{"string1":"192.168.1.40","string2":"8.8.8.8",“string3":“12.34.45.56”,“string4”:408,“string5”:“-”,"string6":1812}
{"string1":"192.168.1.128","string2":"192.168.101.222",“string3":“12.34.45.56”,“string4”:384,“string5”:“-”,"string6":1807}

I did this:

```
example = example.gsub("\n","}\n{\"string1\": \"")                         
example = example.insert(0, "{\"string1\": \"")                  
example = example.concat("}")
```

and I obtained:

{"string1":"192.168.1.40,8.8.8.8,12.34.45.56,408,-,1812}
{"string1":"192.168.1.128,192.168.101.222,12.34.45.56,384,-,1807}

but I don't know how can I do the others changes. Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, to get it as a ruby hash, which you can output as json or whatever you need:

```
out = {}
your_input_data.split(",").each_with_index { |val, i| out["string#{i}"] = val  }
```

(but you would need to do this for each line: input.lines.each { |line| ... do the above here } - but I am not clear - do you want a list of maps?)

Answer (score 1):

I made the assumption that you didn't want values that were just numbers to be double-quoted.

```
DATA.each_line do |line|
    l = line.chomp.split(',').map.with_index do |v, i|
        v = v =~ /^\d+$/ ? v : "\"#{v}\""
        "\"string#{i+1}\":#{v}"
    end
    print "{", l.join(','), "}\n"
end

__END__
192.168.1.40,8.8.8.8,12.34.45.56,408,-,1812
192.168.1.128,192.168.101.222,12.34.45.56,384,-,1807
```

Result:

```
{"string1":"192.168.1.40","string2":"8.8.8.8","string3":"12.34.45.56","string4":408,"string5":"-","string6":1812}
{"string1":"192.168.1.128","string2":"192.168.101.222","string3":"12.34.45.56","string4":384,"string5":"-","string6":1807}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems from the code you wrote that you are looking for a single string as output rather than a more elaborate Ruby data structure or output to a printed stream.

This is working for me:

```
example = '192.168.1.40,8.8.8.8,12.34.45.56,408,-,1812
192.168.1.128,192.168.101.222,12.34.45.56,384,-,1807'

result = example.split("\n").map do |line| 
  n = 0 
  line.split(',').map{|s| %Q|"string#{n+=1}":"#{s}"|}.join(',')
end.map{|c| "{#{c}}"}.join("\n")

puts result

{"string1":"192.168.1.40","string2":"8.8.8.8","string3":"12.34.45.56","string4":"408","string5":"-","string6":"1812"}
{"string1":" 192.168.1.128","string2":"192.168.101.222","string3":"12.34.45.56","string4":"384","string5":"-","string6":"1807"}
```

This splits into lines then splits each line into separate strings, then concatenates each string with its JSON key and finally reassembles with `join` first with commas and then with newline.  If you'd rathet have lists than reassembled strings, just omit the respective join.